# How can i replace a recursive function in python with a non recursive code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to know if there is any other way to do some code that usually requires recursive functions(In python language)

```
def fac(x):
    if x==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*fac(x-1)
x=int(input())
print(fac(x))
```

Comment: Yeah, you can convert recursive code to a while loop, where the negation of the base case is the loop condition, and the parameters to the recursive function are instead values you modify on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Any recursive function can be replaced by a loop.  In this case, it is a simple `for` loop.

```
def fac(x):
    f = x
    for m in range(2,x):
        f *= m
    return f
```